# Bootstrap 4 Horizonal Progress bar border radius opposite like outwards border radius

Tags: bootstrap-4, progress-bar

I am trying to customize the progress bar in which border radius should be clipped outside instead of inside. [Please see the image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxnnf.jpg)

if your see the blue color progress bar left border radius its outwards. I dont understand how border radius will work in negative in progress bar